# Checks (approvals) for a deployment job are blocking the entire stage

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have the following YML file for my pipeline:

```
trigger: none

stages:
# Other stages here...

- stage: Release
  jobs:
  - deployment: Staging
    environment: staging    
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - download: none
          - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
            # ...
          - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
            displayName: Deploy in staging
            # ... 

  - deployment: Production
    environment: prod    
    dependsOn: Staging
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - download: none
          - task: AzureAppServiceManage@0
            displayName: Swap stg-prod slots
            # ...
```

Based on this, to give more context, my thinking is to have 2 stages: the first one is to build my application, the second one is to release in staging (QA) and to production next.

The environment "prod" though, has a check (or approval, whatever you want to call it).

I'm not sure if I'm encountering a bug or not, but what is happening is that when stage 1 completes (the build phase), the release phase of stage 2 is blocked and waiting for approval even considering that "staging" has not any check enabled (only prod).

[image: pipeline]

The easiest workaround is to create different stages, one for staging and one for production, but the thing is that it's not matching my expected behaviour. I'm expecting that the deployment for the job staging completes successfully, then the job "production" waits for the approval.

Do you have any suggestion regarding this? Is this a bug?

Comment: I'm just curious, in Staging why do you have "- download: none" immediately followed by "- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0" - surely there is no point in the first line, so if that isn't a typo/bug, then why?

Comment: I need it to download artifacts from different builds. Anyway it was just a sample, nothing more in this case.

Comment: Ok fair enough :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Checks (approvals) for a deployment job are blocking the entire stage

Sorry for any inconvenience.

Personally, This behavior is by designed at this moment.

As the document state:

> **Approvals in multi-stage YAML pipelines**
>
> We continue to improve multi-stage YAML pipelines, we now let you add manual approvals to
> these pipelines. Infrastructure owners can protect their environments
> and seek manual approvals before a stage in any pipeline deploys to
> them.

This feature is designed based on **stage** not **environment**, so it block the whole stage.

As I test, I could reproduce this issue as you. But your request is reasonable (Personally), this feature should be designed based on **environment**.

You could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your input on this!
In case someone finds this useful too, I'll leave the link to the feedback item here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/673881/dont-block-the-entire-stage-when-checks-approvals.html

Comment: Is there some workaround to work with approvals in YAML script?? , for example Enviroments, Git Repo triggers or Splitting YAML files ? ,another options ?